# Run a php script as daemon on raspban

Tags: php, start-stop-daemon

I wrote a  **working** PHP script with an endless while (true) loop as a Websocket server.

Could you help me with:

1. starting the PHP script on boot ?
2. start stop the PHP script via ssh ?
3. I read about PHP endless loops running out of memory ([ref](http://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die)) is there a better way to maintain a websocket server then?

**FYI**: I have Apache; PHP; MySQL; systemd installed and would like to avoid installing anything else!

**What I tried**:

- writting an init.d/service ([as described by Bram.us](https://www.bram.us/2013/11/11/run-a-php-script-as-a-servicedaemon-using-start-stop-daemon/)) and start it but:

  `sudo /etc/init.d/myservice start`

  `sudo: unable to execute /etc/init.d/myservice: No such file or directory`
- installing upstart  `sudo apt-get install upstart` 
  and writting a config file under /etc/init/ with:

  `start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
  respawn
  exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/script.php`

but I could not boot completely anymore after that ... so I went back to systemd

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) you can do the following:

config file (in /etc/init/) -

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
respawn

exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/script.php
```

This will execute the script on start up and will respawn if the need arises. We're running a websocket service in exactly the same way and we're not having any issues with memory leaks.

Comment: I tried installing upstart  `sudo apt-get install upstart` but could not boot completely anymore after that ... so I went back to systemd